# CSS Toggle Switch to add a class to a DIV with local storage

Tags: javascript, css, local-storage

I'm trying to create a simple toggle switch to add a new class to the body tag. By default the page is red. By clicking the button the page is toggled between red and blue.

Here's the code I have so far - the Switch Colour button would then change the body class tag to blue

```
  <body>
<p>Click the button to change the colour of page</p>
    
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Change background colour</button>
    
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
       var element = document.body;
       element.classList.toggle("blue");
    }
    </script>
    
    </body>
```

The CSS bit

```
body {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

body.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

The bit I'm struggling with is to keep the settings when I refresh the page or move to another page. Is there a way to store this via Local Storage and javascript?

Thanks in advance,
Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The local storage API is super simple to use. `localStorage` is available as a global in the browser, you can store a string value with a key and then retrieve the value with the key.

```
function myFunction() {
       var element = document.body;
       element.classList.toggle("blue");
       var background = localStorage.getItem('background')
      
       if (background === 'blue') {
         localStorage.setItem('background', 'red')
       } else {
         localStorage.setItem('background', 'blue')
       }
    }
    (function() {
      var background = localStorage.getItem('background')
      
      if (background === 'blue') {
        
        document.body.classList.add(background)
      } 
    })()
```

Comment: Hi Spirift, thanks for the solution above, this stores the body.blue state after refreshing the page - but if the red background (default body style) is selected, it always reverts back to the body.blue state once it's changed to blue? - Ideally I need the local storage to remember the body.blue or the default body (red) style. Is this possible?  I'm hoping to style other elements on the page based around either body.blue or the default (red) body style. Essentially I'm trying to switch between the two body classes via the toggle - not just the background colour.

Comment: Apologies I think my original post was a bit confusing! - I hope the above makes sense? - here's a link to my test page - http://dan-mcneil.com/body-class-change.html

Comment: When the page is set back to red, update the local storage again with red

Answer (score 1):

For a more dynamic solution (what happens if you have more than two colors?), I would instead go with a CSS variable, where the default color is red. Stack Overflow doesn't allow reading from localStorage, so I will comment out that code, and instead use a variable  for demo purposes.

I do think the code is self-explanatory.

```js
const BACKGROUND_KEY = 'background';

var forDemoPurposeOnly = '';

function myFunction() {  
  let isBlue = readFromLocalStorage(BACKGROUND_KEY) == 'blue';
  let color = (isBlue) ? 'red' : 'blue';

  setBackgroundColor(color);
}

function setBackgroundColor(color) {
  let root = document.documentElement;
  root.style.setProperty('--user-selected-background', color);
  setInLocalStorage(BACKGROUND_KEY, color);
}

function readFromLocalStorage(key) {
  return forDemoPurposeOnly;
  // return localStorage.getItem(key);
}

function setInLocalStorage(key, value) {
  forDemoPurposeOnly = value;
  // localStorage.setItem(key, value);
}
```

```css
:root {
  --background-color: var(--user-selected-background, red); /* defaults to 'red' */
}

body {
  background-color: var(--background-color);
}
```

```html
<body onload="setBackgroundColor(readFromLocalStorage('background'))">

<p>Click the button to change the colour of page</p>
    
<button onclick="myFunction()">Change background colour</button>

</body>
```